# Ember.js rendering slow in IE 7

Tags: javascript, performance, internet-explorer, ember.js, internet-explorer-7

We created a web application using EmberJS (version 1.0.0-rc5). We notice great performance in Chrome, unfortunately we have to support Internet Explorer 7 as our main platform.

We notice that performance on IE7 is terrible. After investigating the issue, it boils down to the rendering of the template (although routing is also terribly slow). We have no clue if this is due to a mistake in the way we built our application or if this is a problem with Ember.

I created a small sample app to reproduce the problem. You can find it at http://manoswerts.be/playground/ember-performance. It renders a tree similar to what we do in our app. When running it in Chrome, the result shows instantly. In IE7 it takes between 30 seconds up to a minute to render. In IE8 it "only" takes 7 seconds.

Is anyone familiar with this? Is there a solution to this problem?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't know how Ember works, but it looks like you're adding an event listener on every li element. Is that voluntary? Can't you use event delegation?

Comment: With all due respect, how strong is the "we have to support IE7". Is this because your users are actually still stuck on IE7, or is it just because someone decided to specify it as the baseline for support? My point is that IE7 usage has fallen off a cliff in the last 12 months; there really is virtually nobody still using it; certainly not voluntarily. If at all possible, my suggestion would be to drop IE7 support, because yes, it does suck, and yes it does have terrible performance. But most of all because you'll do all the work and nobody will ever actually use it in IE7. What a waste.

Comment: Well it's a problem regardless of IE7 support since it's 200ms on chrome to render 80 items, or is it just me? Core i5 here.

Comment: In case this is helpful. I ran it in IE8 it took less than 2 seconds. Then ran it in IE7 (on browserstack) and it took 20 seconds.

Comment: @Florian I don't know if this is something within our control. I can check this out. @ Spudley I do agree with the fact that IE7 is a bad browser. But we really do not have an option here. The whole company we are building it for is on IE7 and they are not planning to upgrade any time soon. @ jessegavin You seem to have better performance in your tests although I also tested on Browserstack and on a virtual machine. Nevertheless those numbers are still unacceptable.

Comment: Any updates to this issue? We are considering building a web app interface in Ember but unfortunately some of our main clients are also still stuck on IE7 so we have to support it. Any info on this would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following to get some more detail about what is taking so long:

```
Ember.subscribe('render', {
  before: function(name, start, payload){
    return start;
  },
  after: function(name, end, payload, start){
    var duration = Math.round(end - start);
    var template = payload.template || '';
    //console.log(Ember.inspect(payload));
    //var title;
    var view = payload.object.toString();
    console.log('rendered', template, view, 'took', duration, 'ms');
  }
});
```

This will give you timings for every view that is rendered. When I run your example in Chrome each of person templates take about 2ms to render. There is also some overhead related to the nested `{{each}}` helpers and rendering the "virtual" views within those `{{each}}` blocks. In total the list render time is 104ms. That total time will be the last console.log line written after you hit the `Show results` button.

So based on what you're saying I would expect that total time to be an order-of-magnitude slower for ie7 and ie8. If that's the case, wondering if that is distributed evenly or is there a specific view that renders much more slowly.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I will try this and see if the output can enlighten me. I forgot to mention that rendering nested {{each}} blocks in native Handlebars (not through Ember) seems very quick. On top of that the views also add to the overhead which make it unacceptable. I'll keep you posted with the results of the test.

Comment: Quick update: we suddenly got green light to use IE 8 as our target browser. So at the moment this is not an issue anymore for us. However I will try to give @Mike Grassotti his investigation methods a try in my spare time.

Answer (score 0):

For both IE7 and IE8 it is take same time for me, around 4-5 seconds.

Other ember js sample app

https://github.com/dgeb/ember_data_example

not working at all with IE7.